# How can I mask a value from path in a object using ramda

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, ramda.js

This my problem: I had a object or a array of object, and I need mask the value from specifics paths. Like the `password` path in the object below.

```
const obj = { 
          name: 'Jane Doe', password: 'pass', url: '/game?session=0123456789',
          save: {
            url: '/save?session:0123456789',
            password: 'anotherPass',
            deep: {
              password: 'deepPass'
            }
          }, 
}
```

How I can pass a path, like ['password'] to mask just the 1-depth or ['save.password'] or ['*.password'] to replace all.

I can replace the 1-depth with lens, but how can I get a list of paths to replace/set

`getPaths(['password'])(obj)`

Output:

`> [['password'], ['save', 'password'], ['deep', 'password']]`

Answer (score 0):

You create a recursive function that convert the object to an array of `[key, value]` pairs, iterates the pairs, and converts the value if the key matches, or calls the transform function on the value if it's an object.

```js
const { curry, pipe, toPairs, map, is, fromPairs, equals, always } = R

const transformProp = curry((predicate, transformFn, obj) => pipe(
  toPairs,
  map(([k, v]) => [k,
    predicate(k)
      ? transformFn(v)
      : is(Object, v)
        ? transformProp(predicate, transformFn, v)
        : v
  ]),
  fromPairs
)(obj))

const maskPasswords = transformProp(equals('password'), always('********'))

const obj = {"name":"Jane Doe","password":"pass","url":"/game?session=0123456789","save":{"url":"/save?session:0123456789","password":"anotherPass","deep":{"password":"deepPass"}}}

const result = maskPasswords(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ramda does not contain much to help in recursive situations.  But we can build this atop some existing Ramda functions, and some helpers that we can write ourselves now, but which Ramda is [considering adding](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1361#issuecomment-780716313).

Here is one approach, built atop the potential Ramda functions `rebuild` and `remap`:

```js
// utility functions being considered for Ramda
const rebuild = (fn) => (obj) =>
  fromPairs (chain (apply (fn)) (toPairs (obj)))

const remap = (fn) =>
  rebuild ((k, v) => [fn (k, v)])


// main function
const deepRemap = (fn) => 
  remap ((k, v, [nk, nv] = fn (k, v)) => 
    [nk, is (Object) (nv) ? deepRemap (fn) (nv) : nv]
  )


// function for this problem
const maskPasswords =
  deepRemap ((k, v) => [k, k == 'password' ? '********' : v])


// sample data
const obj = {name: 'Jane Doe', password: 'pass', url: '/game?session=0123456789', 'save': {url: '/save?session:0123456789', password: 'anotherPass', deep: {password: 'deepPass'}}}


// demo
console .log (maskPasswords (obj))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {fromPairs, chain, apply, toPairs, is} = R                </script>
```

The helper **`remap`** is much like Ramda's current `map`, but applied to key-value pairs, rather than just the values.  It's structured similarly to the code in the answer from Ori Drori, which runs a transformation function between `toPairs` and `getPairs`.  We might use it to uppercase the keys, and square the values like this:

```js
remap 
  ((k, v) => [toUpper (k), v * v]) 
  ({a: 2, b: 3}) 

//=> {A: 4, B: 9}
```

This is built on top of the more generic **`rebuild`**, which does the same thing, but where your transformation function can return zero, one, or many new key-value pairs.  The *many* case is likely to be unusual, but combining the *zero* and *one* case, thie can work like a `filterMap`, sometimes returning a single transformed pair and sometimes returning none.  For instance, if we wanted to square the values, but skip those whose keys begin with `'_'`, we could do this:

```js
rebuild 
  ((k, v) => k .startsWith ('_') ? [] : [[k, v * v]]) 
  ({_id: 42, a: 2, b: 3, _date: '2021-03-19'})
// => {a: 4, b: 9}
```